# What Syntax is this?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, syntax

I have WordpressTheme and in my MySql Database is Stored a Value like the following.
Its an Optionlist that shows up in an Form, but I never saw something like this.
Any Ideas what this is and how to handle with it?
Or where do find a Documentation about it.

```
a:9:{i:0;a:4:{s:8:"cssClass";s:8:"textarea";s:8:"required";s:9:"undefined";s:6:"values";s:53:"Script (Copy Paste your Script here or Upload a File)";
```

Comment: Looks like result of PHP's `serialize` function

Comment: @Mihai You're wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a string representing a serialized PHP object.

You can get more information about PHP serialization on http://php.net/manual/function.serialize.php

Wordpress and some plugins use PHP serialization to store some internal settings in a database easily.

Comment: Thanks Hauke! Helped a lot. Worked for a couple of Months with Wordpress and sometimes i see thinks i never heard before ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's the result of PHP [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). You can decode it with [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).